# Using wx.lib.agw.artmanager, ArtManager().DropShadow()

Tags: python, window, shadow, wxwidgets

On Windows 7 64-bit, using Python 2.7.3 and wx version 2.8.12.1.

I'm trying to get a wx.Frame styled as wx.SIMPLE_BORDER or wx.NO_BORDER to have a shadow like other windows, like this:

[Drop Shadow](http://i.imgur.com/zcXY3wj.png)

Unfortunately, this seems to be a part of the wx.RESIZE_BORDER style. Here is what happens without that:

[No Shadow](http://i.imgur.com/4j1F2it.png)

So, I went to Googling and found this ArtManager class in the wx.lib.agw.artmanager module, which had a DropShadow function, claiming that it "Adds a shadow under the window (Windows Only)."

But, it didn't seem to do anything. No errors, but no results. Perhaps it doesn't work on Windows 7, but I'm hoping you have a better answer. Of course, I'd be open to other methods of creating a shadow, but this is the one I had found.

Here's my code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.artmanager

class main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, size=(469, 400))
        am = wx.lib.agw.artmanager.ArtManager()
        self.Center()
        self.Show()
        am.DropShadow(self, True)

class app(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = main(None, -1)
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = app()
app.MainLoop()
```